# How can I check if there is a collision?

Tags: events, unity-game-engine, 2d

In my game, I have a ball and ground. The ball is falling and collides with the ground.

But how can I check if the ball has collided? I've added a script to the ball, and got the following code:

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo) 
{
    print ("collision!");
    Destroy(this);
}
```

Problem is that nothing happens, am I using the wrong event? Ultimately I would want to trigger an animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code would work if you were using 3d colliders. However, since you're using 2d, there's a separate event called [OnCollisionEnter2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnCollisionEnter2D.html), so just change your event to this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collisionInfo) 
{
    print ("collision!");
    Destroy(this);
}
```

Comment: Spot on, seems i should try looking for 2D when working in that mode!